# How can I solve "No exact matches in call to initializer" error when I am using Text in SwiftUI?

Tags: text, swiftui

I just started with SwiftUI and have basic questions.
I try to show the value of the rotation in the Text field. The error message I get is: "No exact matches in call to initializer"

Where is the mistake?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

@State var rotation: Double = 0

var body: some View {

    VStack {

        VStack {

        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
            
            Slider(value: $rotation, in: 0 ... 360, step: 0.1)
                .padding()

            Text(rotation)
              
        }
    }
}

}




struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: `rotation` is double type. Init a `Text` view only accepts `String`. 
`Text("\(rotation)")`
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and for fun you can also try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var rotation: Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, world!").rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: rotation)).padding()
                Slider(value: $rotation, in: 0 ... 360, step: 0.1).padding()
                Text("\(rotation)")
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should return a `String` type for initialization of Text, like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var rotation: Double = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Hello, world!")
                    .padding()
                
                Slider(value: $rotation, in: 0 ... 360, step: 0.1)
                    .padding()
                
                Text(rotation.string)
 
            }
        }
    }
}


extension CustomStringConvertible { var string: String { get { return String(describing: self) } } }
```

Comment: This solution is unnecessarily complicated. `Text("\(rotation)")` or `Text(rotation.description)` would suffice, with no `extension CustomStringConvertible` needed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for comment, I didn’t mentioned about those obvious ways because someone explained it in question comment.